# convergence of linear operator $Tx_n\rightarrow f$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assuming $E$ is a Banach space, consider linear operator $T:E\rightarrow E^*$, then for each Cauchy sequence in $E$, is it guaranteed that sequence $Tx_n$ is also Cauchy? i.e., exits $f\in E^*$ such that $Tx_n\rightarrow  f$ ?

If we add new condition, say, $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0, \forall x \in E$ ?

I know linear continuous operator can map cauchy to cauchy, but in my situation, it seems such $f$ doesn't exist.

**original problem**:

Let $E$ be  a Banach space and let $T:E\rightarrow E^*$ be a linear operator satisfying 
$$\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0, \forall x \in E$$
Prove that $T$ is bounded operator. (From: [functional analysis,...](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&source=productsearch&utm_source=HA_Desktop_US&utm_medium=SEM&utm_campaign=PLA&pcampaignid=MKTAD0930BO1&gclid=CMm5qaCL5c8CFVB4gQodPaEKjQ&gclsrc=ds))

A possible counterexample:
$Tx=\infty$ and let $E=\mathbb{R}$, then $T$ is not linear?

Comment: Is map $T$ continuous? What does the new condition mean in a Banach space? The dual space is always complete.

Comment: @copper.hat actually in the book, we want to prove $T$ is bounded(which is equivalent to continuous); by the way I also confusing about the inner product in the new condition. I will put the original problem here.

Comment: If it is not continuous, there is some $x_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$ and $|T x_n| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are discontinuous linear operators from $E$ to $E^\ast$ if and only if $E$ is infinite-dimensional (since $E$ and $E^\ast$ are complete, a map is continuous if and only if it maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences).

Regarding your original problem, it suffices to show that $T$ is closed. Then the closed graph theorem implies that $T$ is continuous.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $E$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $Tx_n\to y$. For all $\alpha>0$, $z\in E$ we have
\begin{align*}
0&\leq \langle T(x_n+\alpha z),x_n+\alpha z\rangle\\
&=\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle+\alpha\langle Tz,x_n\rangle+\alpha\langle T x_n,z\rangle+\alpha^2\langle Tz,z\rangle\\
&\to \alpha\langle y,z\rangle+\alpha^2\langle Tz,z\rangle,\;n\to\infty.
\end{align*}
Dividing by $\alpha$ and letting $\alpha\to 0$ we obtain
$$
0\leq \langle y,z\rangle.
$$
Since $z\in E$ was arbitrary, it follows that $y=0$. Thus, $T$ is closed.

This proof is taken from Kato's *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*. In this book the result is stated for operators on Hilbert spaces, but it carries over almost verbatim to your setting.

Comment: I read this proof, and that's why I ask my question. I am not sure why we can assume $Tx_n\rightarrow y$, where is the $y$?

Comment: $y$ is an element of $E^\ast$. As I said, we only have to prove that $T$ is closed due to the closed graph theorem.

Comment: I know. but do we need to prove the existence of $y$,cause no theorem say that $Tx_n$ convergence

Comment: Yes, but I ASSUME that $(Tx_n)_n$ converges.

Comment: according to the condition of the original problem, I don't think we can assume the $Tx_n$ converges, do we?

Comment: Please look up the definition/characterization of closed operators. It's the whole point of the closed graph theorem that we can assume that $(Tx_n)_n$ converges.